# In border-box menu, the border applied to the menu button and menu items is not aligned correctly

Tags: css

I have created a css dropdown menu.

The menu items have the same width as the menu button. But on applying border to the menu button and menu items (menu items are positioned absolutely)(used border-box for both menu button and menu items), the borders are not aligning correctly

Please see [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/kififijawu/1/edit?html,css,output)

### HTML Code

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

div.time {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: limegreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 50%;
}

div.time:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}


div.time > div {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.time:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: lightgrey;
}

div.time:hover > div {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}

div.time > div > div {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

div.time > div > div:hover {
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="time">
    Time
    <div>
      <div>AM</div>
      <div>PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening even thought the menu button and menu items have the same width. Also both of them have the same box-sizing: border-box property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `border` for the dropdown divs, you can use `outline`. In your case, you should have the css:

```
div.time:hover > div {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background-color: white;
  outline:1px solid limegreen;
}
```

The reason why it changes the size of the dropdown divs is the border. Width the extra width from the border, it makes the dropdown divs width to be the same as that of the main div without its border.

Comment: Thank you, this works spectacularly. This is the first time I have heard about outline.

Answer (score 2):

Using an outline instead of a border is often a good alternative if one doesn’t want the “border” to affect element dimensions and/or position. (1+ to Kevin for this answer.) Plus, the `outline-offset` property allows for some quite nice effects, too.

If you don’t want to or can’t use an outline for some reason, then you can also quite simply solve this by not specifying a width for those inner div elements, and position them `left: -1px; right: -1px;` to “offset” the effect of the parent border on the width calculation.

(Pretty long code snippet for such a short answer ;-)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

div.time {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: limegreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 50%;
}

div.time:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}


div.time > div {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.time:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: lightgrey;
}

div.time:hover > div {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  /*width: 100%;*/    /* These are the only */
  top:100%;           
  left:-1px;          /* three changes      */
  right:-1px;         /* I made             */
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
}

div.time > div > div {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  color: darkgrey;
}

div.time > div > div:hover {
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="time">
    Time
    <div>
      <div>AM</div>
      <div>PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very helpful. I wish I could upvote this answer, but I can only vote after earning 15 reputation points.